# Bokeh - Issue responsive design with Flask and Bootstrap4

Tags: flask, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, responsive, bokeh

I am developing an dashboard with Flask, Bootstrap4 and Bokeh. However, I cannot get a stable responsive design with bokeh. I have eight tabs with each two bokeh plots. The tabs are hidden via javaScript so can select a tab and it will be shown. The responsiveness is only working for the default visible tab. Accordingly, for the first tab the plots adjust to the given size. However, for the other tabs (same css, same html) the plots do not limit to the given css boundary and occupy a bigger space as the div they live in actually has. And, once I go back to the default visible tab, also those plots lost their responsiveness and behave like all the others.

I am using the sizing mode: "stretch both" and limit the height of the plots via css.

I would be thankful if someone could point me towards the solution. Cheers Lars

Here is my plotting code:

```
def plottingto(dataframe, lineID, plotnametext ):

    names = lineID

    source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'date'      : dataframe['date'],
    'time'      : dataframe['time'],
    'index'     : dataframe.index,
    'pendeltime_To_Real': dataframe['pendeltime_To_Real'],
    'pendeltime_To': dataframe['pendeltime_To'],
    'pendeltime_Back_Real': dataframe['pendeltime_Back_Real'],
    'pendeltime_back': dataframe['pendeltime_back'],
    'delay_to': dataframe['delay_to'],
    'delay_back': dataframe['delay_back'],
    })

    hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Uhrzeit', '@time'),('Pendelzeit', '@pendeltime_To_Real'),('Verzögerung','@delay_to')], names=names)
    tools = [hover_tool, ResetTool(), BoxZoomTool()] #WheelZoomTool(), PanTool(),

    #Bokeh Plott Rückweg Live Today
    p = figure(plot_height=320, x_axis_type="datetime", y_range=(26, 60),tools=tools, sizing_mode="scale_width")
    p.line(x='index', y='pendeltime_To_Real',line_width=1, line_color="#7db800", legend="Echte Pendelzeit", name=names[0], source=source)
    p.line(x='index', y='pendeltime_To', line_width=1, line_color="red", legend="Durchschnittliche Pendelzeit", source=source)
    p.toolbar.logo = None
    plotname = file_html(p, CDN, plotnametext)
    return plotname
```

Here is my css (in addition to bootstrap4):

```
.fixed_height{
      height:380px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
    <div class="row mainrow">
        <button class="accordion">
            <h3 class="headingfullrow">STATISTIKEN ZUM PENDELFENSTER</h3>
        </button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm diagrambox">
                        <div class="x_title">
                            <h2>Verkehrslage letzte 7 Werktage Hinweg</h2>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x_panel tile fixed_height overflow_hidden">
                            {{BOKEHWEEKTO | safe}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm diagrambox">
                        <div class="x_title">
                            <h2>Verkehrslage letzte 7 Werktage Rückweg</h2>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x_panel tile fixed_height overflow_hidden">
                            {{BOKEHWEEKBACK | safe}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```